# Preventing Gson deserializing JSON String of a List to actual ArrayList

Tags: java, gson, deserialization, json-deserialization

Here is my code

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(inputFile), map.getClass());
```

The content of the `inputFile` is

```
{
  "key1": "[\"value1\"]",
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

When I inspect the value of `map.get("key2")` during debugging in Eclipse, the value is actually `(java.util.ArrayList<E>) [value1]`

How can I make Gson deserialize the content to

```
{key1="[value1]", key2=value2}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like you are seeing the `HashMap#toString()` output of

```
{key1=["value1"], key2=value2}
```

and thinking that

```
["value1"]
```

is a `List` of some type, containing a `String` value of `"value1"`.

It isn't. Your `String`, as a `String` literal, would be represented as `"[\"value1\"]"`. Its value is `["value1"]`. That's what gets displayed.

Both your JSON key-value entries are `string-string` and will get converted as such.

```
"key1": "[\"value1\"]",
//      ^ indicates a JSON string
```

Comment: The test code snippet I tried also worked, regardless of loading the source String from file or variable in memory. The complete case is I have some other code that down loads the file from S3 and return me a File object. I would get this deserialization error if I do not write the File to a local file. After writing the file locally and reopening the local file with FileReader and passing it to the fromJson method, everything is working as expected.

Comment: @derrdji So was it just an interpretation problem or something else?